# Connect two PIs to wso2 iot server from admin user

Tags: server, wso2, raspberry-pi3, iot

Previously I have connected one raspberry pi to my wso2 IOT server and it worked fine. It sent temperature data & turned on/off bulb correctly. Now I have connected another raspberry pi with different device ID. Actually I have enrolled a new raspberry pi device to management console. They have two different names & ids. But when I run both testAgents no one works correctly. No one sends temperature data & switches on/off the bulb. What they only do is connecting to the broker & disconnecting from the broker & nothing else. When first one is connected to broker 2nd one gets disconnected. When second one is connected 1st one gets disconnected. What can I do???????????? 
any help please....

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the issue described here? :

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Accessing+API+Manager+by+Multiple+Devices+Simultaneously

Maybe you just can create other user with necessary permissions and set that in the other device.

Comment: Something similar to that problem. I have tried with different users. But same thing happens

Comment: I have tried with a different user with all permissions. but same thing happens.

Comment: The problem is both cannot connect to server at one time.

Comment: Have you looked in logs?


<IOTS_HOME>/repository/logs

Can you please provide some?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2019:16:59:27 +0530] "POST /oauth2/token?scope=Enroll+device&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=800a9c52-d1dd-3c1f-91ee-2e5d7bc55bf6 HTTP/1.1" 400 62 "-" "Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2019:16:59:28 +0530] "POST /services/OAuth2TokenValidationService HTTP/1.1" 200 718 "-" "Axis2"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2019:16:59:35 +0530] "POST /oauth2/token?scope=Enroll+device&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=800a9c52-d1dd-3c1f-91ee-2e5d7bc55bf6 HTTP/1.1" 400 62 "-" "Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO"

Comment: this is the complete log. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IhQyafddzNbcYJ1CEFfiGmnbKZbNkWYi

Comment: This is what happening in two terminals..... When both run together               https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zaohgVXsbXID6KxJxM1xz3UADbtfZaI8

Comment: Can u please help on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743538/wso2-iot-server-with-raspberry-pi